# Why MouseEvent.buttons is always set to 1 when using Page.mouse.move(x, y) using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, puppeteer

I was comparing mouse movement events of a Firefox browser controlled by Puppeteer and one controlled by me (a human, I think...) and noticed that events emitted by Puppeteer always have the [**MouseEvent.buttons**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons) property **set** to **1**, even when I don't have any button pressed and events emitted by humans always have this property set to 0 (when any button is pressed, of course).

What am I missing here?

To reproduce the behavior, just run this code snippet locally:

```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    product: 'firefox', // <== This is important
    defaultViewport: null,
    devtools: true,
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.setContent(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            html, body, #target {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="target">test</div>
          <script>            
            const target = document.getElementById('target')

            target.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
              console.log(event)
            })
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `)

  await page.mouse.move(100,100)
```

Now, run the code and inspect the events on the console.

I honestly think this is a bug or something within pptr and Firefox (chrome seems to not have this) but I don't want to fill a bug report without getting more opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that Firefox is the one that set the value of `MouseEvent.buttons` to 1 in any `MouseEvent` sent over DevTools Protocol.